# POST Request is Successful but GET Request is Null

Tags: c#, http, post, entity-framework-core, get

I have a model called Players that is used within another model called Teams. After POSTing, the GET Request shows that the players data within teams comes back null whereas everything else returns as expected. See my code below.

Player model:

```
    public class Player
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Teams Model:

```
    public class Team
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public IList<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }
```

Teams GET Request:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Team>>> GetTeams()
        {
            return await _context.Teams.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Teams POST Request:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Team>> PostTeam(Team team)
        {
            _context.Teams.Add(team);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTeam), new { id = team.Id }, team);
        }
```

POST Request JSON on Swagger (FYI this posts successful):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "team name",
  "location": "team location",
  "players": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "firstName",
      "lastName": "lastName"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Teams GET Request Returned JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "string",
    "location": "string",
    "players": null
  }
]
```

How do I get the "players" data to return the inputted data as expected?

Comment: What is the result of your call to `_context.SaveChangesAsync()`?

Comment: @CodexNZ it returns 201 and the response is {"id":1,"name":"team name","location":"team location","players":[{"id":1,"firstName":"firstName","lastName":"lastName"}]}

Comment: Try `return await _context.Teams.Include(t => t.Players).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @anastaciu You just fixed an issue in a few minutes that I struggled with all day lol thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, it's what I do. To be fair, it was in a few seconds ;)

Comment: @anastaciu Well I have a similar issue with my put request where it updates the team but not the players within it. Any tips for that?

Comment: @anastaciu the code in the function is _context.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: @YoungLightning it's only that? It's not much to go on, you should probably ask a new question. FYI, when eager loading the entity is normally tracked, so when you save the changes made to it, the context should recognize the differences by itself, if that's not the case you should mark as modified the entity you get from db and perform changes on, if it's a player or more, that's what you should mark as modified.

Comment: @anastaciu check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73780166/get-request-with-id-param-and-put-request-do-not-affect-my-model-class-within-my I asked it here. I am more of a novice when it comes to C# so forgive me if it's simple lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use explicit loading to load your players collection:

```
foreach(var team in teams) 
{
    var players = context.Entry(team)
        .Collection(b => b.Players)
        .Query();
}
```

Or eager loading:

```
await _context.Teams.Include(t => t.Players).ToListAsync();
```

Also you can be interested to [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) article by Microsoft to find out more about loading related entities.